# How to use the PDE toolbox to solve $u_t=u_{xx}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

Yesterday, I use the PDE toolbox of Matlab solve some PDE, it is very interesting, but seemly, only 2-dimension it works. In fact, I want to use it for  equation like
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+V(x)u
$$
I can't found it how to work on 1-dimension domain, so I use it as picture below, it work well, but I can't get a 1-dimension picture which I want to use in my work. How should I do it ?  I want the picture like the second picture below . Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't need PDE toolbox for that. MATLAB has [`pdepe`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html) for that.

Comment: @m0nhawk  Thanks very much, when I have time, I will try it. Thanks again.